# Генератор списка с несколькими листами

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, циклы, list

Вопрос по генераторам списков:

```
import numpy as np
import math

X = [0.1035 , 0.2286]; Y = [0 ,0.0451]

r2 = []
r2x = [[(n-j)**2 for x, j in enumerate(X) if x != y] for y, n in enumerate(X)]
r2y = [[(k-l)**2 for x, l in enumerate(Y) if x != y] for y, k in enumerate(Y)]
r2x,r2y,r2 = map(np.array, [r2x,r2y,r2])
r2 = (r2x+r2y)
print("r2",np.array(r2))
```

Результат:

```
 r2 [[ 0.01768402]
     [ 0.01768402]]
```

Можно ли уместить в генератор `r2` циклы `r2x` и `r2y`?

Вместо 2-х отдельных генераторов списка и `numpy` метода - один генератор списка:

```
r2 = [ (n-j)**2 + (k-l)**2 ... ]
```

Comment: Можно, но тогда он будет совершенно нечитабельным. Поэтому лучше так не делать и не желать странного. Если очень хочется, то можно попробовать, например, [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: А почему бы например этот код не разбить на много маленьких функций? Тогда и дублирование логики пропадет, и понятнее будет происходящее.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np


def fill_r2(arr):
    return [
        [(n - i) ** 2 for x, i in enumerate(arr) if x != y]
        for y, n in enumerate(arr)
    ]


X = [0.1035, 0.2286]
Y = [0, 0.0451]

r2x = fill_r2(X)
r2y = fill_r2(Y)

r2x, r2y = map(np.array, [r2x, r2y])
r2 = r2x + r2y
print("r2:\n", np.array(r2))
```

Консоль:

```
r2:
 [[ 0.01768402]
 [ 0.01768402]]
```

---

Можно немного уменьшить код за счет его читаемости:

```
...

X = [0.1035, 0.2286]
Y = [0, 0.0451]

r2 = sum(map(np.array, [fill_r2(X), fill_r2(Y)]))
print("r2:\n", np.array(r2))
```